# spring dependency injection using RMI

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, rmi, code-injection

suppose we have 2 projects ProjectA(front end) and ProjectB(back end) and 2 classes ClassA in ProjectA and ClassB in ProjectB.
Now I need to get the instance of ClassB in ClassA. 
The question is how to organize injection of ClassB into ClassA by using Spring and RMI? What to add into spring.xml?
I'm new in java so  if you can provide the answer with exampls please.
Thanks in advance!!

```
public void initializeManager() {
  InitialContext context = null;
  if (manager == null) {
    try {
      Properties props = TaxFormsConfiguration.getInstance().getProperties();
      context = new InitialContext(props);
      manager = (EFormsManager) context.lookup("taxsystem/EFormsManagerFacade/remote");
      if (manager == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("EFormsManager is null.");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("error in EFormsActionManager.initializeManager: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [Spring reference for remoting](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/remoting.html). Yuu can find an example there (chapter 19.2 Exposing services using RMI)

Instead of context lookup you will declare your beans in XML and get them via Spring application context, for example:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(yourxmlname);
EFormsManager eFormsManager= (EFormsManager)context.getBean("eFormsManager");
```

XML on RMI server side:

```
<bean id="eFormsManager" class="example.EFormsManagerImpl">
    <!-- any additional properties, maybe a DAO? -->
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <!-- does not necessarily have to be the same name as the bean to be exported -->
    <property name="serviceName" value="EFormsManagerService"/>
    <property name="service" ref="eFormsManager"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.EFormsManager"/>
    <!-- defaults to 1099 -->
    <property name="registryPort" value="1199"/>
</bean>
```

XML on RMI client side:

```
<bean id="eFormsManager" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://HOST:1199/EFormsManagerService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.EFormsManager"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick response! i saw that tutorial before but still i cannot apply it for my project.
specifically speaking i have method "initializeManager()" which does what i want but not by injection, here is the code

Comment: public void initializeManager() {
  InitialContext context = null;

  if (manager == null) {
   try {
    Properties props = TaxFormsConfiguration.getInstance().getProperties();
    context = new InitialContext(props);
    manager = (EFormsManager) context.lookup("taxsystem/EFormsManagerFacade/remote");
    if (manager == null) {
     throw new RuntimeException("EFormsManager is null.");
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("error in EFormsActionManager.initializeManager: " + e.getMessage());
   }
  }
 }

Comment: now if u can please give some advice how to do that, i need to delete this method and as i understand - add "something" to spring.xml, but what to add i don't know :(